# Dynamic dot menu in Google Workspace Add Ons

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I am building a Google Workspace Add-On and want to use the dot menu to dynamically display a "Sign Out" option after a user has logged in.

I found out that the menu options are defined in the deployment resource of an Add-on (also called manifest) as an array called "universalActions". For example like this:

```
"universalActions": [{
        "label": "Settings",
        "openLink": "https://myapp.com/settings"
      },{
        "label": "Sign Out",
        "openLink": "https://myapp.com/logout"
      }]
```

But I can't find a way to change the "universalActions" after deployment.

In the example below you see the Evernote Add-on before login and after login.

[image: Evernote before login]
[image: Evernote after login]

On the second picture, so after the login, you see the additional menu options "Einstellungen" (meaning settings) and "Abmelden" (meaning logout). How can I achieve displaying these options after login only?

Answer (score 1):

The feature I was looking for is called [CardActions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-action). If you define a "CardAction", it will be placed in the header bar menu (what I referred to as "dot menu").

As JSON-Object, you can put it like that:

```
"action": {
      "navigations": [
        {
          "pushCard": {
            "cardActions": [
              {
                "actionLabel": "Logout",
                "onClick": {
                  "openDynamicLinkAction": {
                    "function": "https://dummy-function-from-resources.net/openLinkCallback"
                  }
                }
              }...
```

Answer (score 1):

*Universal actions, according to Apps Script documentation are:*

> [...] menu item elements that allow a user to open a new web page, display new UI cards, or run a specific Apps Script function when selected. In operation they are very similar to card actions, except that universal actions are always placed on every card in your add-on, regardless of the current add-on context.

Indeed, using a card action seems like the appropriate choice for this, however, you might also consider checking the other widgets options available, as they allow the add-on to do something based on the user interaction:

- DateTime pickers;
- Image button;
- Selection input;
- Switch;
- Text button;
- Text input;
- Grid;

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Widgets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/widgets#user_interaction_widgets);
- [Apps Script Build Interactive Cards](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/interactions).